# Google Chrome page is infected by the Ukash virus

Tags: google-chrome, malware, chromebook

I have a Samsung Chromebook. On the Google Chrome page I can't get rid of a site called Ukash (some site masquerading as Europol or something).

How can I get rid of it?

Comment: You can't run Windows applications on a Chromebook. Please describe the circumstances in greater detail: How and when exactly does Ukash open?

Answer (score 2):

Run a POWERWASH on your ChromeBook.

It should be found under Settings -> PowerWash.